# How to add a "buy now" button below "add to cart" button

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In woocommerce, I would like to add a "buy now" button below the "add to cart" button that would redirect to the cart page. The button could look similar to the "add to cart" button.
It would be great if this "buy now" button everywhere.
I guess this button would require to add the product to the cart before redirecting to the cart page.

Comment: `add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'content_after_addtocart_button' );`
 
`function content_after_addtocart_button() {
echo '<div class="content-section"><br/><input type="button" value="Button"/></div>';
}  `  Copy the code to your functions.php and you will get the result

Answer (score 1):

This [Woocommerce quick buy](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-quick-buy/) plugin does it and will add the button you want. It has shortcodes and other nice features